# Defining a generic function for iterated function composition

Tags: matlab, function, handle

Let us define any function handle `foo`:

```
foo = @(x) x*2
```

I am trying to write a general function `defFun` that generates the [*n*-th functional power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Functional_powers) of the function `foo`, i.e. *n* iterative calls of `foo`, in a way it can be stored in another handle function `boo`, like this:

```
boo = defFun(foo,n)
```

For example,

```
foo = @(x) x^2;  
boo = defFun(foo,3);
```

`boo(3)` will give `6561 [== foo(foo(foo(3)))]` and `boo(2)` will give `256 [== foo(foo(foo(2)))]`.

I tried this code to write `defFun` but these handles are tricky to deal with. Any ideas?

```
function boo = defFun(foo,n)
   h = foo;
   for i=2:n
      h = h(h);
   end
   boo = h
end
```

Comment: So you are looking for an alternative to [_fnest](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/_fnest.html), not requiring MuPAD.

Comment: Thank you all for the different answers. @knedlsepp's solution is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My code pretty much resembles your original one. I took the liberty to rename a few of the variables.

### Direct approach:

For single input and single output argument you could use the direct approach resembling your code:

```
function ftoN = fIterate(f, N)
    ftoN = f;
    for i = 2:N
        ftoN = @(x) f(ftoN(x)); 
    end
end
```

### Indirect approach: (possibly faster)

This one will be a lot faster and it will also work for multiple (but same number of) inputs and outputs.

```
function ftoN = fIterate(f, N)
    ftoN = @(varargin)   fIterateLocal(f, N, varargin{:});
    function varargout = fIterateLocal(f, N, varargin)
        varargout = varargin;
        for i = 1:N
            [varargout{1:nargin-2}] = f(varargout{:});
        end
    end
end
```

### Example:

Both approaches should work with this:

```
square = @(x) x^2;
square(2)
>> ans = 4

squaresquaresquare = fIterate(square, 3)
squaresquaresquare(3)
>> ans = 6561
```

### Aftermath:

The **direct approach** will be rather slow and also limited by the `Maximum recursion limit` of MATLAB.

```
timeit(@()feval(fIterate(@(X)X+1,400),0))
ans = 1.2160
```

The **indirect approach** will give you a lot more speed and flexibility:

```
timeit(@()feval(fIterate(@(X)X+1,400),0))
ans = 0.0072
```

Comment: Nice one, although I preferred your indirect approach _before your edit_, because it left the name of the base function in the function definition. Since your edit it is all gone now, but still works perfect though.

Comment: Oh, I just did it so both versions will have the same interface. I think if anyone wants to have good readability of the final handle, your version is preferable anyway!

Comment: I liked the idea of your indirect approach

Answer (score 3):

The 3 solutions here rely on building a string then using `str2func` to get a function handle out of it. Different implementations for the same functionality but different readability of the result.

Note that as highlighted in the comment (*thanks knedlsepp*), the order of recursion `n` cannot exceed `32`.

---

One way is to parse the input function string definition and recreate it recursively in a string before converting that to a function handle:

```
function boo = defFun(foo,n)

   %% // retrieve the string of the initial function
   A = functions(foo) ;
   fstrfull = A.function ;

   %% // find "input variables" in the header
   [i1 i2] = regexp(fstrfull, '\(([^\)]+)\)' , 'once' ) ;   %// probably can be improved, regexp are not my strong suit
   strVar = fstrfull(i1+1:i2-1) ;  %// =>  strVar='x'       %// to get rid of the parenthesis returned by the regex

   %% // isolate only the function expression (without the header)
   ilast = strfind( fstrfull , ')' )+1 ;  %// ilast= 5      find the last position of the header
   fstr = fstrfull(ilast(1):end) ;        %// fstr='x.^2'   separate only function expression

   %% // replace "variables" by the expression the desired number of time
   strFinalFunction = fstr ;
   for i=2:n
      strFinalFunction = strrep(strFinalFunction, strVar, ['(' fstr ')'] ) ;
   end
   boo = str2func( ['@(' strVar ')' strFinalFunction ] ) ;

end
```

This will give you:

```
>> boo = defFun(foo,3)
boo = 
    @(x)((x.^2).^2).^2 // <= your function shows the full expression

>> boo(3)
ans =
        6561
```

It will work for much more complex cases as long as the input function only take **one** variable as input.

---

Alternatively, there is a simpler method which should be even more generic. It requires no parsing and thus and will work in the potential case the parsing in the solution above fails. The downside is the function definition become very opaque.

```
function boo = defFun2(foo,n)

cfoo = {foo} ; %// place the function handle in a cell

%// create a string calling the function on itself N number of times
strFun = ['@(x) ' repmat('cfoo{1}(',1,n) 'x' repmat(')',1,n) ] ;

%// Generate a function handle for the corresponding function
boo = str2func( strFun ) ;
```

But now your function definition look like this:

```
>> boo = defFun2(foo,3)
boo = 
    @(x)cfoo{1}(cfoo{1}(cfoo{1}(x))) // <= your function does not show what it does (only the number of time it calls itself)
```

Much less readable, but it still gives the right results.

---

Lastly, if readability is critical, you can also include the name of the original function in the function definition but you'll have to resort to the controversial `eval`.

```
function boo = defFun3(fh,n)

fname = inputname(1) ;        %// get the name of the function which was called
eval( [ fname '={fh};' ] ) ;  %// place the function handle in a cell

strFun = ['@(x) ' repmat([fname '{1}('],1,n) 'x' repmat(')',1,n) ] ; %// create a string calling the function on itself N number of times
boo = str2func( strFun ) ;                                           %// Generate a function handle for the corresponding function
```

This now gives you:

```
boo = defFun3(foo,3)
boo = 
    @(x)foo{1}(foo{1}(foo{1}(x))) // <= now you know that boo is the function 'foo' called on itself 3 times.
```

Comment: This is as fast as my for-loop approach + has added readability. The only downside being `str2func`'s odd limitation for the recursion depth of only 33. (I get the error `Nesting of {, [, and ( cannot exceed a depth of 32.` when calling with `n=34`)

Comment: Thanks @Hoki, I liked your idea

Answer (score 1):

If your function handle `foo` only contains mathematical formulas (as is the case in your example), you can use the MATLAB Symbolic Toolbox, to calculate the formula for `boo`

```
function boo = defFun(foo,n)
    syms x;                    % Create a symbolic variable x
    f = sym(foo);              % Convert the function handle to a symbolic expression
    g = symfun(f,x);           % Create a symbolic function to work with

    v = g;
    for k=2:n                  % repeat n times
        v = g(v);
    end

    boo = matlabFunction(v);   % convert v to a function handle
end
```

In your example for `n=3`, this creates the function handle

```
foo = @(x) x.^2;
boo = defFun(foo,3)
boo = 
    @(x)x.^8

boo(3)
ans =
    6561
```

Answer (score 0):

You just just got your variables mixed up a bit. Your issue is that you feed in the function handle to the anonymous function rather than the value.

This will work, building on your example.

```
foo = @(x) x^2;

function boo =  defFun(fcn_handle,n)

   v = fcn_handle(n); % The output here is the value of the anonymous function
   for i=2:n
     v = fcn_handle(v); 
   end
   boo = v;
end

defFun(foo,3)

ans =  6561
```

Comment: That's quite nice to give the result of the full calculations, but i was under the impression the OP wanted to return a `function handle` to a new function, not just the result.

Comment: @Hoki I didn't understand the question in that why. I guess the key is the interpretation of ` store it`. `it` could be the value or the function. I think it's a bit harsh to downvote this though.

Comment: the downvote is not me. I was just about to upvote when I tried your answer and realized it wasn't complete, but I surely didn't downvote. It is still a valid partial answer, it does the calculations right.